# PBS batch file submission with changes in the .py file

Tags: python, pbs

Say that I create a Python PBS file submission that looks like this:

```
!/usr/bin/python
# Example PBS cluster job submission in Python

from popen2 import popen2
import time

#PBS -M email
#PBS -m abe  # (a = abort, b = begin, e = end)

# Loop over your jobs
for i in range(1, 10):

    # Open a pipe to the qsub command.
    output, input = popen2('qsub')

    # Customize your options here
    job_name = "job%s" % str(i).zfill(3)
    walltime = "24:00:00"
    processors = "nodes=1:ppn=1"
    command = "./file%s" % str(i).zfill(3)

    job_string = """#!/bin/bash
    #PBS -N %s
    #PBS -l walltime=%s
    #PBS -l %s
    #PBS -o ./output/%s.out
    #PBS -e ./error/%s.err
    cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
    %s""" % (job_name, walltime, processors, job_name, job_name, command)

    # Send job_string to qsub
    input.write(job_string)
    input.close()

    # Print your job and the response to the screen
    print job_string
    print output.read()

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I execute this code in Python on the Unix system. I would like to know, is it possible to make a change in `file1.py`,`file2.py`... when submitting each PBS file? In each `file%s.py`, there is a variable `date` (ex `date='2010-01-20'`) for which I would like to change every time a submit a new PBS batch files. Can this be initiated in the above code without having to change the dates manually in each `file1.py`,`file2.py`...?

Comment: The job you are submitting is a shell script. What are `file1.py` and `file2.py`? Is this the python script you posted?

Comment: @Oz123 yes I am submitting the above shell script. The `file1.py` files are python codes that will be executed in each processors `ppn=1`. Its in these files that I need to make a change to the `date`.

Comment: @Oz123 I think I am complicating myself way too much. I think I have a solution...

Comment: If those file1.py and file2.py are files that are going to be read and executed mid-job, then changing them should take effect for all jobs that haven't run yet.